# EJS template with custom data not rending some key values inside an object

Tags: node.js, nestjs, ejs

I want to render an ejs file with custom values in my NestJs application. This is my template:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center bg-violet-800"> 
    <h3 style="color: white; text-align: center"><%= name %></h3> <br /> 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <p class="my-text-class"> <%= details %> </p> 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <% for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) { %> 
                <div> <img src="<%= images[i] %> "/> </div> 
            <% } %> 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-4">  
            <h3 style="color: white; text-align: center">COURSES</h3> <br /> 
            <% for ( let i = 0; i < courses.length; i++ ) { %> 
                <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                    <h4> <%= courses[i].title %> </h4> <br /> 
                    <p class="my-text-class"> <%= courses[i].details %> </p> 
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <% if (courses[i].images && courses[i].images.length ) {
                            for ( let j = 0; j < courses[i].images.length; j++) { %> 
                                <div> <img src="<%= courses[i].images[j] %> " /> </div> 
                            <%  } 
                        } %> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            <% } %> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

When I render this ejs file, using the following code :

```
async getCampus(id: string) {
    const campus = await this.campusModel.findById(id);
    const selectedTemplate = await this.templateService.getTemplate({
      isSelected: true,
    });
    try {
      const templateContent = await fs.readFile(
        selectedTemplate?.path,
        'utf-8',
      );
      const renderedTemplate = ejs.render(templateContent, {
        name: campus?.name,
        details: campus?.description,
        images: campus?.images,
        courses: campus?.courses,
      });
      return renderedTemplate;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Error rendering template: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
```

the courses[i].details and courses[i].images are not rendering. But when I use ***console.log(courses[i])*** I'm getting the full data in object. But I didn't get them when I try to access it separately.
I don't know what is the issue here.

```
{
  "name": "Barnard College, Columbia University",
  "description": "new college/university",
  "images": [
    "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pexels.com%2Fsearch%2Ffree%2F&psig=AOvVaw1zoOph-5L4G0VPUcshccgQ&ust=1692262413006000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCICPpPPm4IADFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"
  ],
  "courses": [
    {
      "title": "Marketing",
      "images": [
        "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pexels.com%2Fsearch%2Ffree%2F&psig=AOvVaw1zoOph-5L4G0VPUcshccgQ&ust=1692262413006000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCICPpPPm4IADFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"
      ],
      "details": "Unique courses and comprehensive academies provide unparalleled college-prep experiences. "
    }
  ]
}
```